# Formula to calculate 4 best golf scores from gross and net without using same player for both

Tags: datatable

This is related to Golf scores so the lower scores are better.

In golf, you have a gross score and a net score. We have 6 player teams. We are taking the 4 best scores out of 6 each league night. However, the 4 best scores must be 2 gross and 2 net and it CANT be the same person for both. I am struggling to find a way to use a formula to pull the best 4 scores (2 gross and 2 net) without using the same player for both.

In the example I provided, we manually used the 37 and 38 from the Net side as those were the 2 lowest. Then we used the 42 and 48 on the gross side as that was the next 2 lowest on the gross side that wasn't a repeat of a net player. Those 4 best scores totaled together = 165.

To be consistent, I have player names from D8 to D13. Gross scores are in G8 to G13 and Net scores are H8 to H13.

Thank you for your help

[Player Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acT1s.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is a programming Q&A site. You should try to ask a _specific_ question about a _specific_ programming problem you are facing - ideally by showing us the code you have tried in the question, what happened when you tried it, and what you wanted to happen instead. You also need to use your question's tags to let us know what technology you are actually trying to use. If you hover your mouse over the `datatable` tag in the question, you should understand what I mean. The one tag you have chosen does not help us at all.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask] for more general guidance.